# iOS devices act different in some cases

Tags: ios, iphone, navigation

I recently ran into a problem when a back navigation works fine most of the devices, but on some it just doesn't work, it doesn't navigate back. The code is really simple, nothing special.

On an API callback I show an alert controller and when the user hits OK I navigate back him/her.

```
 warnUserWithTitle(title, message: message) {
        _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Has anyone experienced like this?

Comment: Are you sure the code is being called? You say *"On an API callback..."* -- I'm assuming you mean a "remote server API", so is it possible your API is failing and your code does not "call back"?

Comment: I'm sure. The alert controller did show up, but when the OK tapped the navigation didn't advance